# Connecting to a port on Fargate

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, gunicorn

I'm trying to learn how to deploy a gunicorn/flask app using ecs-cli. I see the task running from the aws console after running ecs-cli compose service up, but am unable to access the app from the provided public IP followed by :5000. I tried to change the ports from 5000 to 80 in the docker-compose-yml but that doesn't work either. It runs locally (when I comment out the logging directives for aws). What am I missing?

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    image: 81234567878.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/myapp-gunicorn:v1
    build: ./services/web
    command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 project:app
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    logging: 
      driver: awslogs
      options:
        awslogs-group: my-site
        awslogs-region: us-east-2
        awslogs-stream-prefix: myweb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Fargate task's security group, you should allow the port 5000. if your task is part of a service, then you should do allow the port in the service's security group.

Comment: Wow... that's totally it. It works now, thanks for the quick response. So if I wanted it to listen on port 80. What do I need to do?

Comment: do you have a load balancer configured? if yes, you map load balancer's port 8o to the fargate tasks's port 5000

Comment: I do not. I just have whatever comes with the default ecs-cli up command. I followed these instructions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cli-tutorial-fargate.html

Comment: when you change the ports to `80:80`, where is it erroring

Comment: I ge this error when trying to change all the instances of 5000 to 80.
`web_1  | [2020-08-17 10:31:43 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0', 80)`

Comment: try to change the ports to as `80:5000`. it means map the container port `5000` to host port `80`

Comment: The ports have to match when deploying as Fargate. It gives this error when you try 80:5000
`FATA[0000] ClientException: When networkMode=awsvpc, the host ports and container ports in port mappings must match.`

Comment: when you tried port `80`. did you change all the instances of the `5000` including `command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:80 project:app`

Comment: I did. It doesn't like it when I change it to:
`command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:80project:app
    ports:
      - 80:80`

Comment: Where did you get the error, in yaml or in aws console

Comment: In the Task Logs. It also doesn't work locally when you change the ports to 80.

Comment: In your docker file, can you change `- 5000:5000` to `- "80:80"` . note the quotes around the port.

Comment: ignore the message above. most likely the port 80 may be in use? can you check whether you have any web servicer running such as nginx or apache